# get nearest coordinates from pandas df from centroid of coordinates

Tags: python, pandas

i have a pandas df

```
id     x_value  y_value
100     1       2
200     3       1
300     5       3
400     3       6
500     3.2     3.5
600     4.5     3
```

i want to find the middle point from these coordinate pairs, such that 
it will return the most nearest dataframe row from the middle point coordinates.

```
def get_centroid(df):
    lat_mean = df['x_value'].mean()
    lat_mean = df['x_value'].iloc[(df['x_value']-lat_mean).abs().argsort([:1]].tolist()[0]
    long_mean = df['y_value'].mean()
    long_mean = df['y_value'].iloc[(df['y_value']-long_mean).abs().argsort()[:1]].tolist()[0]
    return([lat_mean,long_mean])
```

But this approach is wrong, as i would not get exact pairs of df.

Is there any other way of doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The center will just be the average x and y which you can get with

```
df.mean()

x_value    3.283333
y_value    3.083333
dtype: float64
```

This gets you the location of the min squared distance from the mean

```
df.sub(df.mean()).pow(2).sum(1).idxmin()

500
```

This gets you the row

```
df.loc[[df.sub(df.mean()).pow(2).sum(1).idxmin()]]

     x_value  y_value
id                   
500      3.2      3.5
```

---

**Setup**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'x_value': [1.0, 3.0, 5.0, 3.0, 3.2, 4.5],
        'y_value': [2.0, 1.0, 3.0, 6.0, 3.5, 3.0]
    }, pd.Index([100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600], name='id')
)
```

Comment: Impressive, concise syntax. I didn't realise that `sqrt` isn't even needed.

Comment: Thanks @EricDuminil.  Yeah, monotonic relationship with `sqrt` so the position of min doesn't change.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for the smallest euclidian distance, you can calculate the distance to the center for each row and pick the minimum one:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> 
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([{'y': 2.0, 'x': 1.0, 'id': 100}, {'y': 1.0, 'x': 3.0, 'id': 200}, {'y': 3.0, 'x': 5.0, 'id': 300}, {'y': 6.0, 'x': 3.0, 'id': 400}, {'y': 3.5, 'x': 3.2, 'id': 500}, {'y': 3.0, 'x': 4.5, 'id': 600}])

>>> df = df.set_index('id')
>>> df
       x    y
id           
100  1.0  2.0
200  3.0  1.0
300  5.0  3.0
400  3.0  6.0
500  3.2  3.5
600  4.5  3.0
>>> center_x, center_y = df.mean()
>>> np.sqrt((center_x - df['x'])**2 + (center_y - df['y'])**2)
id
100    2.527295
200    2.102512
300    1.718688
400    2.930396
500    0.424918
600    1.219517
dtype: float64
>>> (np.sqrt((center_x - df['x'])**2 + (center_y - df['y'])**2)).idxmin()
500
>>> df.loc[(np.sqrt((center_x - df['x'])**2 + (center_y - df['y'])**2)).idxmin()]
x    3.2
y    3.5
Name: 500, dtype: float64
```

As far as I can tell, it's the same method as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45418353/get-nearest-coordinates-from-pandas-df-from-centroid-of-coordinates/45418947#45418947), but less concise.